# I am doing some calculation but unable to parse a string into int or even in float

Tags: android

i want to update the total value which is display in main activity edittext while deleting the data from listview so am getting the deleted data from adapter and sending to main activity but i got this error log

i have get "data" from listadapter

```
**Main activity code:**

    public Broadcast Receiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                      primary = intent.getIntExtra("key",0);

                        totalview.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(totalview.getText().toString()) - primary));
                        total= Integer.parseInt(totalview.getText().toString());

                }
            };

**Adapter code:**

 holder.floa.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                **dvalue= Integer.parseInt(row_pos.getPrate());**
                Intent intent = new Intent("custom-message");
                **intent.putExtra("key",dvalue);**
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
                rowItems.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
```

here is my logcat

```
Process: com.example.baytatest, PID: 3439
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
        at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
        at com.example.baytatest.scanbilling$10.onReceive(scanbilling.java:396)
        at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:313)
        at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage(LocalBroadcastManager.java:121)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5474)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: i have updated about my problem